# How create static library using system libraries?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I wrote a simple `C++` program using `ntl` libraries. I try to create a static library from my program. I used these commands :

```
g++ -Wall -g -c base.cpp -o base.o
ar rcs libMyStaticLib.a *.o
```

`libMyStaticLib.a` was created successfully. But when I used `libMyStaticLib.a` in another project I get these error:

```
g++ -o main.out main.cpp -lMyStaticLib
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libMyStaticLib.a(base.o): In function `NTL::Vec<NTL::GF2>::~Vec()':
/usr/local/include/NTL/vec_GF2.h:43: undefined reference to `NTL::WordVector::~WordVector()'
```

my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include </home/Qwer/test/base.h>

int main()
{
    baseInit();
    return 0;
}
```

I try to link `ntl` library while creating static library

```
ar rcs libMyStaticLib.a *.o -lntl
```

But I get this error :

```
ar: two different operation options specified
```

I want to try static library and use it in anoother project. How should I so this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static libraries are nothing more that *archives* (that's what the `ar` program creates, and the `.a` suffix stands for) of object files. Linking with a static library is like linking with the objects files inside the archive.

That's why all other libraries that your static library depends on *also* must be linked:

```
$ g++ -o main.out main.cpp -lMyStaticLib -lntl
```

Comment: Thanks. But I should compile the code without using ntl library (envireonment does not have it). Is there a way integrate ntl with myStaticLib (or something else) ?

Comment: @user4757345 Do you mean you build your library on a system which have ntl installed, and you want to use your library on a system where ntl is not installed? Most projects just lists their dependencies and ask their users to install the dependencies (ntl in your case). Other than that the only solution is if ntl have a static library, where you can extract the object files from their library and add to yours. There might be licensing implications with that solution though.

Comment: yes. I want to create a static library with all dependencies and other programmer should only use my library not ntl or other system libraries. Is that possible ?

Comment: @user4757345 Realistically? No it's not possible. You either have to include the library with your distribution of your library, or tell the users of your library to install the needed dependencies (which is the most common).